# How to extract azure resource template format either via REST API, Powershell or Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rest-api

Is there a way to extract azure resource template formats programmatically (REST API, Powershell, Azure CLI)?

The end result should be something along the lines of the JSON presented here, that includes datatypes etc.:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?tabs=json

Preferably being able to select API-version too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.KeyVault/2015-06-01/vaults?tabs=json

I have tried using `az provider` and expand properties, but properties are always null.

```
az provider show -n Microsoft.KeyVault --expand resourceTypes/properties
```

`az resource` seems only to work on existing resources.

Comment: if you use az rest, it should work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest

Comment: Thanks @Thomas
Can you tell me which endpoint to hit if I want to get the template for e.g. the Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?
I can't find any information about this.

I can find the REST endpoints for key vaults, but that does not provide the template definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract Azure ARM template format, try the PowerShell below:

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.KeyVault/2019-09-01/vaults"
 
$webRequest.ParsedHTML.getElementsByClassName("lang-json") | % innerHTML
```

It works under 5.0:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Stanley. 
I am not too happy about scraping for a long-term solution. I would prefer a more reliable method,
But this will do for a start.

Comment: @TechnoCowboy， I see, pls share your final solution in the end and if my post is helpful in the end, pls accept it :)

Comment: @TechnoCowboy， How's going? Do you have any other solutions? As far as I  know , this is the only way to do this. If you find other ways, pls share it thx !

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But I will use your solution for now, and continue my search :-)